# (Wordpress) Can not get future_to_publish to work

Tags: wordpress, post, transition, status

So I have spent the past 2 hours trying to figure out why future_to_publish will not work. Here is a list of what i have checked to work.

1. draft_to_publish
2. future_post
3. publish_post
4. transition_post_status(works draft to future, but not future to publish

I can't seem to figure out the problem. I'll include the test code I'm using below. Send help....

```
function on_post_scheduled($ID, $post) {
$fp = fopen(get_template_directory()."/files/foo.php",'r+');

    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      
    fwrite($fp, "future post published".mt_rand( 0, 255 ));
    fflush($fp);           
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    }

}
add_action('future_to_publish','on_post_scheduled',10,2);
add_action('new_to_publish','on_post_scheduled',10,2);
add_action('draft_to_publish','on_post_scheduled',10,2);
```